# MySQL + Query to return all rows that have cols that are 'active' in another table

Tags: mysql

I am looking for some help on how to go about this query..  and also about doing in an efficient way as well.

I am -not- that experienced with MySQL/queries (my skills get cloudy at about the JOIN level!.. lol)..

So I will sacrifice some efficiency for -readable- code/query that I actually understand as well.  :)

I have an example Rextester set-up for you to look at as well:

http://rextester.com/FWVO47690

- I know there is a lot of columns currently.. (some will be going away).. the key column is the ingredient_code that matches the drink and ingredients table.
- For the drinks table.. I can do it like how I have it outlines there...

or I can have just one ingredients column... but the data would be like:

Which is the action (serial) data that will get sent out from the drink menu interface..  if that makes it easier to use instead of separating each ingredients, position and amount into separate columns for all possibly 15?

Summary:
I am creating a front end interface (webpage).. that is hosted on a Raspberry Pi with LAMP installed (more or less)..

This is a drink menu.=
The 'drink table' is more or less a 'library' of all drinks...

When the 'page' loads.. I want to run/execute a query to return all drinks from the drink table.. that have a 'matching and active' ingredient in another table.  (hope that makes sense?)

So the drink menu is sort of 'dynamic' based on the ingredients table..

If a drink needs:

orange juice and vodka..

It will not be active or display in the drink menu if in the ingredients table orange juice or vodka is not active...etc..

** Each drink can have from 1 to 15 ingredients...

So I'm not sure how to go about doing this with a query?  I'm sure if will need some joins and sub queries...

So I'm looking for some guidance (at least on what key words to search on..etc)

I feel like this isnt going to be very efficient?  (while I'm not worried too much about 'speed' since it only needs to load once upon each power-cycle....  I dont want it to lag out or anything..LOL)

I fudged together this attempt.. but this doesnt allow for multiple ingredients in a drink.. I only did '1'..

```
SELECT * FROM barbot_drinks AS drinks
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients AS ingredients 
  WHERE drinks.ingredient_1_code = ingredients.ingredient_code
)
```

Something like this give false positives.. because one of the ingredients could be missing..  but a previous or later one does 'match'.. hence it gets returned  (when it shouldnt)

```
SELECT * FROM barbot_drinks AS drinks
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients AS ingredients    
  WHERE drinks.ingredient_1_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_2_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_3_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_4_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_5_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_6_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_7_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_8_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_9_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_10_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_11_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_12_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_13_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_14_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 
    OR drinks.ingredient_15_code = ingredients.ingredient_code 

);
```

---

Update on Nicks provided solution:

** Was looking for an update because if you alter the table, by removing (say) the ingredient_x_dispenser value (or _code or _dosage).. but leave the other it still gets returned..

for each drink row, each *#* ingredient needs to have ALL 3 fields (_dispenser, _code, _dosage) != ''...   && also have that ingredient_code in the other table & active)..  sorry if I am not relaying this correctly.

@Nick   (like this?)

```
SELECT * 
FROM barbot_drinks d
WHERE (ingredient_1_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_1_code = '' AND ingredient_1_dosage = '' OR 
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_1_code)) AND
    (ingredient_2_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_2_code = '' AND ingredient_2_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_2_code)) AND
    (ingredient_3_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_3_code = '' AND ingredient_3_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_3_code)) AND
    (ingredient_4_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_4_code = '' AND ingredient_4_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_4_code)) AND
    (ingredient_5_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_5_code = '' AND ingredient_5_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_5_code)) AND
    (ingredient_6_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_6_code = '' AND ingredient_6_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_6_code)) AND
    (ingredient_7_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_7_code = '' AND ingredient_7_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_7_code)) AND
    (ingredient_8_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_8_code = '' AND ingredient_8_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_8_code)) AND
    (ingredient_9_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_9_code = '' AND ingredient_9_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_9_code)) AND
    (ingredient_10_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_10_code = '' AND ingredient_10_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_10_code)) AND
    (ingredient_11_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_11_code = '' AND ingredient_11_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_11_code)) AND
    (ingredient_12_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_12_code = '' AND ingredient_12_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_12_code)) AND
    (ingredient_13_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_13_code = '' AND ingredient_13_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_13_code)) AND
    (ingredient_14_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_14_code = '' AND ingredient_14_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_14_code)) AND
    (ingredient_15_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_15_code = '' AND ingredient_15_dosage = '' OR
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_15_code));
```

I feel like it should be more like this:  (but this returns zero rows)

```
SELECT * 
FROM barbot_drinks d
WHERE (ingredient_1_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_1_code != '' AND ingredient_1_dosage != '' AND 
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_1_code)) AND
    (ingredient_2_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_2_code != '' AND ingredient_2_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_2_code)) AND
    (ingredient_3_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_3_code != '' AND ingredient_3_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_3_code)) AND
    (ingredient_4_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_4_code != '' AND ingredient_4_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_4_code)) AND
    (ingredient_5_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_5_code != '' AND ingredient_5_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_5_code)) AND
    (ingredient_6_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_6_code != '' AND ingredient_6_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_6_code)) AND
    (ingredient_7_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_7_code != '' AND ingredient_7_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_7_code)) AND
    (ingredient_8_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_8_code != '' AND ingredient_8_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_8_code)) AND
    (ingredient_9_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_9_code != '' AND ingredient_9_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_9_code)) AND
    (ingredient_10_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_10_code != '' AND ingredient_10_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_10_code)) AND
    (ingredient_11_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_11_code != '' AND ingredient_11_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_11_code)) AND
    (ingredient_12_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_12_code != '' AND ingredient_12_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_12_code)) AND
    (ingredient_13_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_13_code != '' AND ingredient_13_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_13_code)) AND
    (ingredient_14_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_14_code != '' AND ingredient_14_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_14_code)) AND
    (ingredient_15_dispenser != '' AND ingredient_15_code != '' AND ingredient_15_dosage != '' AND
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_15_code));
```

re-cap:

I only want to return drinks, from the drinks table that:

- If there is a value in ingredient_x_dispenser, -or- ingredient_x_code, -or- ingredient_x_dosage.. that all '3' value for *x* are present..  (_dispenser, _code, _dosage make up 1 'ingredient' in my mind for discussion purposes, and there can be 1 - 15 'ingredients' per recipe (row), hope that makes sense)
- if in the drinks rows there is a -3- ingredient requirement met, than it also has to be found in the other ingredients table as ACTIVE and with the matching _CODE, (as it does now).. if the first part of the criteria that its getting by on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by saying you really need to normalise your database. But that is another question. In the meantime, you can use this query. I've only shown it for four ingredients, you would need to extend it to 15 for your case.

```
SELECT * 
FROM barbot_drinks d
WHERE (ingredient_1_dispenser = '' OR 
       EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_1_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_1_code)) AND
      (ingredient_2_dispenser = '' OR
       EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_2_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_2_code)) AND
      (ingredient_3_dispenser = '' OR
       EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_3_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_3_code)) AND
      (ingredient_4_dispenser = '' OR
       EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_4_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_4_code))
```

With your sample data, this produces the following output:

```
id  drink_id    drink_name   drink_image      drink_desc                    ingredient_1_dispenser  ingredient_1_code   ingredient_1_dosage     ingredient_2_dispenser  ingredient_2_code   ingredient_2_dosage     ingredient_3_dispenser  ingredient_3_code   ingredient_3_dosage     ingredient_4_dispenser  ingredient_4_code   ingredient_4_dosage
1   vdk_org     Screw Driver screw_driver.jpg Screw Driver description...   bottle  vdk     1   valve   oj  2000                                                                                                                                                            
2   vdk_cran    Cape Cod     cape_cod.jpg     Cape Cod description...       bottle  vdk     1   valve   cbj     2000                                                                                                                                                            
3   dry_mrtn    Dry Martini  dry_martini.jpg  Dry Martini description...    bottle  vdk     2.5     bottle  vrmth   .5  valve   orgbit  200
```

**Edit**

Based on somewhat extended discussions with OP, the query has been refined as below. This query requires that dispenser, code and dosage are all present for each ingredient in the drink. An [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/296b5/3) is available.

```
SELECT * 
FROM barbot_drinks d
WHERE (ingredient_1_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_1_code = '' AND ingredient_1_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_1_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_1_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_1_code)) AND
      (ingredient_2_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_2_code = '' AND ingredient_2_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_2_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_2_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_2_code)) AND
      (ingredient_3_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_3_code = '' AND ingredient_3_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_3_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_3_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_3_code)) AND
      (ingredient_4_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_4_code = '' AND ingredient_4_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_4_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_4_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_4_code)) AND
      (ingredient_5_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_5_code = '' AND ingredient_5_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_5_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_5_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_5_code)) AND
      (ingredient_6_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_6_code = '' AND ingredient_6_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_6_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_6_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_6_code)) AND
      (ingredient_7_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_7_code = '' AND ingredient_7_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_7_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_7_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_7_code)) AND
      (ingredient_8_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_8_code = '' AND ingredient_8_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_8_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_8_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_8_code)) AND
      (ingredient_9_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_9_code = '' AND ingredient_9_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_9_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_9_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_9_code)) AND
      (ingredient_10_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_10_code = '' AND ingredient_10_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_10_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_10_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_10_code)) AND
      (ingredient_11_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_11_code = '' AND ingredient_11_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_11_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_11_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_11_code)) AND
      (ingredient_12_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_12_code = '' AND ingredient_12_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_12_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_12_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_12_code)) AND
      (ingredient_13_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_13_code = '' AND ingredient_13_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_13_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_13_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_13_code)) AND
      (ingredient_14_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_14_code = '' AND ingredient_14_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_14_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_14_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_14_code)) AND
      (ingredient_15_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_15_code = '' AND ingredient_15_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_15_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_15_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_15_code))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. I'll give the query a try.. thanks.

Can you expand on what you mean by 'normalize'?  (for those with not a lot of DB exposure?)

Comment: Too long to explain for a comment, but this [blog](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/) gives a fairly good introduction to normalisation and why it's a good thing.

Comment: Appreciate the link.  (off to read about it now in fact)  Thank you.

Comment: Question:Why are you checking for a blank/empty ingredient_x_dispenser value?  (as the first part of the 'OR' check?)

-
-
FROM barbot_drinks d
WHERE (ingredient_1_dispenser = '' OR


Why would you want to select a drink if there was not a dispenser value set for that column?

ingredient_1_dispenser = ''

Comment: Because not all your `ingredient_x_dispenser` columns have values in them so this is to make sure that blank ingredients don't cause the `WHERE` condition to fail. I've used `''` because that's what it looked like your blank data was; if it's actually `NULL` you'd change that part of the condition to `ingredient_1_dispenser IS NULL OR`

Comment: The 'ingredient_x_dispenser' must contain a value if there is a value in matching other two columns.  (ingredient_x_code & ingredient_x_dosage)..  right now if the other two columns arent blank..but dispener is..and the other ingredients are there.. it still returns  (ie: blanking out dispenser value)..  I'll check NULL)

Comment: That was my assumption (so why I didn't also include a check that ingredient_x_code & ingredient_x_dosage were also empty). But if one ingredient is empty, the `EXISTS` clause will return false so we need to check for an empty ingredient to make sure the `WHERE` clause as a whole can still return true (as it `AND`s all the terms together).

Comment: I changed = '' OR  to IS NULL OR.. and it returned zero rows.

I reverted back to your original.. and it of coursed worked and returned rows.. 

-however-.. as mentioned above, if I, say, remove the dispenser value (ingredient_1_dispenser) in  The Screw Driver drink entry.. it still returns but if there is no dispenser, ..  that should invalidate the drink from being returned.

Comment: Ok, then you probably need to change `ingredient_1_dispenser = ''` to `ingredient_1_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_1_code = '' AND ingredient_1_dosage = ''` in each line

Comment: I updated the original post with what I believe you suggested for me to do... it still returns that screw driver (orange juice and vodka) drink...even though the dispenser value is empty.

Comment: Ok, my misinterpretation. You will need to change each line of the `WHERE` clause to `ingredient_1_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_1_code = '' AND ingredient_1_dosage = '' OR 
    ingredient_1_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_1_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_1_code)) AND`

Comment: That did not help..   it returns zero rows now as well...I had also updated the original post to what I 'think/feel' it should look like.. that too also returns zero rows..

I can throw up some rextester examples if that helps?

Comment: I created [one] at http://rextester.com/ANUWA71765 (only with an edit to the first ingredient) and it seems to be working fine...

Comment: I didnt see any edits or a query in your link? (looks like the original?.. maybe I'm missing something?) Here are two query examples

http://rextester.com/OYM37587

http://rextester.com/IKXXVU78261

One that returns rows.. and one that one it shouldnt..

Here is one where I made an edit to the first drink entry, and it have a missing ingredient_1_dispenser value  (but yet it still gets returned.. it should not get returned)....  The other doesnt returns any rows

Comment: Sigh... seems like I can't get rextester to work. I've tried again: http://rextester.com/RZXI72814 but if that doesn't work I also made an SQLFiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/296b5/3 both of these return 3 drinks from the raw data, then if you remove dispenser or code or dosage for a drink they no longer return that drink.

Comment: I've edited my post with the new query. Is it working?

Comment: Yes.. it is working,. I have accepted your answer as well.

I am now trying to tweak it a bit more.. as I realize I left out a huge part of the query need.

The query, as it stands, is working and is returning the correct numbers of available drinks expected, and the correct drinks.

What I need to do now is tweak the query to include some 'substitute' data from the barbot_ingredient table..

So for each:

ingredient_x_code 

column that has data in it.. I would like to return the dispenser_order that matches that ingredient_x_code.

Comment: Hope that makes sense?  I'm not sure how to go about getting for each not empty ingredient_x_code column.

Comment: Can we make it a new question?

Comment: Sure.. any tips on how and what to post in it?   Basically.. this is current query.. I want it to do X, Y, Z?

Comment: Yes - just like that. Include a link to the working SQLFiddle. Say that it's a follow-on from this question and link back to it.

Comment: You may even end up with a better solution to this question!

Comment: New question posted:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870190/mysql-adjusting-current-query-to-get-additional-data-from-another-table-per-c