# MySQL + Adjusting current query to get additional data from another table (per column)

Tags: php, mysql

This a new question/update from a previous thread.
[MySQL + Query to return all rows that have cols that are 'active' in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804664/mysql-query-to-return-all-rows-that-have-cols-that-are-active-in-another-tab/51804795?noredirect=1#comment90690633_51804795)

I am using PHP and MySQL to return some data with a query thank to the help of member @Nick

I currently need help in tweaking the current query to somehow return substitute data from another table in the rows/data it is currently returning.

Here are some current examples of what the table set-up is like, and the current query state:

REXTESTER:
http://rextester.com/RZXI72814

SQL FIDDLE:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/296b5/3

It currently works as I outlined in the previous request, but once I put it to use, I realized I missed a requirement, which in hindsight I feel is fairly significant...LOL (sorry)

Current State: (working as expected)
Query that returns all rows from the 'barbot_drinks' table [that has (1-15) ingredients made up of (3 cols each) _dispenser# _code# & _dosage#]..  that are EACH found in the barbot_ingredients table AND are active.

If any of the _dispenser# _code# & _dosage# cols are empty, the whole 'ingredient' is invalid...and empty fields dont count...usually signify the end of the drink recipe (a drink can only have a max of 15 ingredients)

example:
if a drink recipe/entry only has 2 'ingredients'  (ingredient_1_dispenser, ingredient_1_code, and ingredient_1_dosage & ingredient_2_dispenser, ingredient_2_code, and ingredient_2_dosage)

VODKA & OJ

it checks the ingredients table to see if both VODKA and OJ entries exist in the barbot_ingredients table AND are active.

So thats where we are now.

What I need to try and do is get the 'dispenser_order' value from the barbot_ingredients for -EACH- ingredient_x_code column (which could be 1-15 per drink)..for each drink that gets returned. (ie: all ingredients for that paticular drink are found in the ingredients table and are active)

I am parsing each row and creating a string using PHP from the result set from this query.

what I am currently creating:

Example (Screw Drive Drink):
(after being parsed  by php script)

bottle=vdk:1,valve=oj:2000

or  (col names)

[ingredient_1_dispenser]=[ingredient_1_code]:[ingredient_1_dosage],[ingredient_2_dispenser]=[ingredient_2_code]:[ingredient_2_dosage]

what I need to build is this:

bottle=1:1,valve=1:2000

or

[ingredient_1_dispenser]=**[###dispenser_order - FROM_INGREDIENT TABLE THAT MATCHES THIS SETS - = ingredient_1_code###]**:[ingredient_1_dosage],[ingredient_2_dispenser]=**[###dispenser_order - FROM_INGREDIENT TABLE THAT MATCHES THIS SETS - = ingredient_2_code###]**:[ingredient_2_dosage]

ie: (after being parsed  by php script)

**bottle=**[###dispenser_order - FROM_INGREDIENT TABLE THAT MATCHES THIS SETS - = ingredient_1_code###]**:1,**

**valve=**[###dispenser_order - FROM_INGREDIENT TABLE THAT MATCHES THIS SETS - = ingredient_2_code###]**:2000**

The current is long because of the 1-15 possible column combination, but I also asked for something was easily readable so I can also understand and learn from it.. (like I have so far!)..

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide, or if I made anything unclear.  I wanted to give full background, links to working code, and examples of what I am getting/doing, and what what I -want- get/do.

Comment: Too much explanation?  Not clear?  Too hard to accomplish?  LOL.. Anything? Is there something more I can provide to get some direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things are starting to get really messy because the database isn't normalised. This query will give you the results you want. Unfortunately it got too big for SQLFiddle... But rextester seems to handle it - [here is the new one](http://rextester.com/AIHN62985).

Here is the output:

```
id  drink_id    drink_name      drink_image         drink_desc                  ingredient_1_dispenser  ingredient_1_code   ingredient_1_dosage     ingredient_1_dispenser_order    ingredient_2_dispenser  ingredient_2_code   ingredient_2_dosage     ingredient_2_dispenser_order    ingredient_3_dispenser  ingredient_3_code   ingredient_3_dosage     ingredient_3_dispenser_order
1   vdk_org     Screw Driver    screw_driver.jpg    Screw Driver description... bottle                  vdk                 1                       1                               valve                   oj                  2000                    1       
2   vdk_cran    Cape Cod        cape_cod.jpg        Cape Cod description...     bottle                  vdk                 1                       1                               valve                   cbj                 2000                    2   
3   dry_mrtn    Dry Martini     dry_martini.jpg     Dry Martini description...  bottle                  vdk                 2.5                     1                               bottle                  vrmth               .5                      7                               valve                   orgbit              200                     3
```

Here's the updated query:

```
SELECT id, drink_id, drink_name, drink_image, drink_desc,
    ingredient_1_dispenser, ingredient_1_code, ingredient_1_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_1_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_1_code), '') AS ingredient_1_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_2_dispenser, ingredient_2_code, ingredient_2_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_2_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_2_code), '') AS ingredient_2_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_3_dispenser, ingredient_3_code, ingredient_3_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_3_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_3_code), '') AS ingredient_3_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_4_dispenser, ingredient_4_code, ingredient_4_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_4_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_4_code), '') AS ingredient_4_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_5_dispenser, ingredient_5_code, ingredient_5_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_5_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_5_code), '') AS ingredient_5_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_6_dispenser, ingredient_6_code, ingredient_6_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_6_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_6_code), '') AS ingredient_6_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_7_dispenser, ingredient_7_code, ingredient_7_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_7_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_7_code), '') AS ingredient_7_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_8_dispenser, ingredient_8_code, ingredient_8_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_8_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_8_code), '') AS ingredient_8_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_9_dispenser, ingredient_9_code, ingredient_9_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_9_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_9_code), '') AS ingredient_9_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_10_dispenser, ingredient_10_code, ingredient_10_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_10_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_10_code), '') AS ingredient_10_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_11_dispenser, ingredient_11_code, ingredient_11_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_11_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_11_code), '') AS ingredient_11_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_12_dispenser, ingredient_12_code, ingredient_12_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_12_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_12_code), '') AS ingredient_12_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_13_dispenser, ingredient_13_code, ingredient_13_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_13_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_13_code), '') AS ingredient_13_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_14_dispenser, ingredient_14_code, ingredient_14_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_14_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_14_code), '') AS ingredient_14_dispenser_order,
    ingredient_15_dispenser, ingredient_15_code, ingredient_15_dosage,
    COALESCE((SELECT dispenser_order FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_15_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_15_code), '') AS ingredient_15_dispenser_order
FROM barbot_drinks d
WHERE (ingredient_1_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_1_code = '' AND ingredient_1_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_1_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_1_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_1_code)) AND
      (ingredient_2_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_2_code = '' AND ingredient_2_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_2_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_2_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_2_code)) AND
      (ingredient_3_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_3_code = '' AND ingredient_3_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_3_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_3_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_3_code)) AND
      (ingredient_4_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_4_code = '' AND ingredient_4_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_4_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_4_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_4_code)) AND
      (ingredient_5_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_5_code = '' AND ingredient_5_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_5_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_5_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_5_code)) AND
      (ingredient_6_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_6_code = '' AND ingredient_6_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_6_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_6_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_6_code)) AND
      (ingredient_7_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_7_code = '' AND ingredient_7_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_7_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_7_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_7_code)) AND
      (ingredient_8_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_8_code = '' AND ingredient_8_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_8_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_8_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_8_code)) AND
      (ingredient_9_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_9_code = '' AND ingredient_9_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_9_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_9_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_9_code)) AND
      (ingredient_10_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_10_code = '' AND ingredient_10_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_10_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_10_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_10_code)) AND
      (ingredient_11_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_11_code = '' AND ingredient_11_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_11_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_11_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_11_code)) AND
      (ingredient_12_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_12_code = '' AND ingredient_12_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_12_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_12_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_12_code)) AND
      (ingredient_13_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_13_code = '' AND ingredient_13_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_13_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_13_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_13_code)) AND
      (ingredient_14_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_14_code = '' AND ingredient_14_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_14_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_14_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_14_code)) AND
      (ingredient_15_dispenser = '' AND ingredient_15_code = '' AND ingredient_15_dosage = '' OR
       ingredient_15_dosage != '' AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM barbot_ingredients i WHERE i.active = 1 AND i.dispenser_type = d.ingredient_15_dispenser AND i.ingredient_code = d.ingredient_15_code))
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm on my way to work.. so will try to give 'it a go' sometime today!  Appreciate the eyes..

Re: Normalizing - I skimmed over the link... and understood the article as ensure each table only deals with specific aspects of the project..

When I thought about how that could apply to my current set-up.. the only thing I could come up was possibly breaking out the drink image, description..etc stuff out into a new table.. (but wasnt really sure that was worth it.. or how it would help the query being easier?)